# simple php class to store user information

Tags: php, oop

I am desperately trying to learn how to use classes in PHP.  I'm trying to make a simple class to replicate a bad habit of storing user information as an array that I'll use in functions by setting it as "global" first.

Below is my very clumsy attempt at making this class.  It doesn't work for 100 reasons.  Can you fix it?

```
class user{
    private $user;
    function __construct(){
        $user=/*some SQL to create a $user array.  Assume one pair is 'firstname'=>'Brian'*/
    }

    function showValue($key) {
        echo $user[$key];
    }

    function changeValue($key,$newValue) {
        $user[$key]=$newValue;
    }
}

echo "Hello there ".user->showValue('firstname')."!";  //should echo: Hello there Brian!

user->changeValue('firstname',"Steven");
echo "Now your name is ".user->showValue('firstname'); //should echo: Now your name is Steven

//the same class needs to work inside a function too
function showLogin() {
   echo "Logged in as ".user->showValue('firstname');
}
showLogin(); //Should echo: Logged in as Steven
```

**UPDATE**

The reason why I don't want to do this as an array anymore is because I'm frequently having to use the array inside functions like this:

```
function showLogin() {
    global $user;
    echo "Logged in as ".$user['firstname'];
}
showLogin();
```

I want to avoid using the "global" in there since I have been told that this is evil.

And I don't want to pass $user to showLogin() like showLogin($user).  In this very simple case it makes sense but when I'm doing very complicated functions that draw on many arrays like this, I don't want to have to pass every array through.

Comment: This is worse then a simple casual array. You made a wrapper for array. And moreover you've done it wrong way. :) You have magic methods like __set and __get to do this.

Comment: Posting the errors you're getting would be a good place to start getting help...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why are you not using Session Variables? Store the User information in a Session.

Comment: I updated my reason why I need to do this.  It's not just user's information.  There's lots of different arrays of information I (think I) need to do this for.  The alternative is $GLOBALS or global and I've been told those are bad.

Comment: Global variables has nothing in common with what you are doing here. To use a class, you have to create an instance of it (an object). Which is also a variable, just like an array. So what's the difference? You still have to pass it somehow to places where you want to use it.

Comment: @dragoste I'm starting to see what you're talking about.  It's been very confusing to have my "global" practices be called wrong.  And then always be told that classes are "right".  I always just assumed this was the right to right the wrong.  Do you know of a better way of avoiding using global or $GLOBALS inside functions for things like user/site settings?

Comment: Generally: passing references. ;) More specifically: designing architecture of code it probably the hardest task in programing.You should learn a lot about object programming and design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call $user as property to set the value

```
class user{
     private $user;
     function __construct(){
        $this->user= ....
     }

function showValue($key) {
    echo $this->user[$key];
}

function changeValue($key,$newValue) {
    $this->user[$key]=$newValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Donald, can you show how I would then call variables for the user array?  Was the way I was doing it correct? user->showValue('firstname')

Comment: You have to create an instance of User class (`$someUser = new user();`), the you can use it like this: `$someUser->showValue('firstname');`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have an instance of the class `$instance = new user();`

Also in order to access members in the class you need to use `$this->`

Your code should look like this:

```
class user{
    private $user;
    function __construct(){
        $this->user=/*some SQL to create a $user array.  Assume one pair is 'firstname'=>'Brian'*/
    }

    function showValue($key) {
        echo $this->user[$key];
    }

    function changeValue($key,$newValue) {
        $this->user[$key]=$newValue;
    }
}

$instance = new user();

echo "Hello there ".$instance->showValue('firstname')."!";  //should echo: Hello there Brian!

$instance->changeValue('firstname',"Steven");
echo "Now your name is ".$instance->showValue('firstname'); //should echo: Now your name is Steven

//the same class needs to work inside a function too
function showLogin() {
    echo "Logged in as ".$instance->showValue('firstname');
}
showLogin(); //Should echo: Logged in as Steven
```

Comment: I got an error saying there shouldn't be a [ at $this->user->[$key]

Comment: I made it $this->user->$key instead and now get an error "Call to a member function showValue() on a non-object" while inside the showLogin() function.